# How to list most recent 10 remote branches in git

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to get most recent 10 remote branches using git. I know I can use `git branch -r --sort=-committerdate` to get all remote branches sorted by committerdate. But I want to know, how I can select the most 10 recent remote branches ?

Comment: Use `head -n 10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pipe it to `head`:

```sh
git branch -r --sort=-committerdate | head -n 10
```